# Fixed-point theorem on $[0,1]$ applications in stochastic control

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, control-theory, fixed-point-theorems, applications

I was looking at this very [old paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212878?seq=1) on [a specialized case of the Knaster-Tarski fixed-point theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2700152/fixed-point-of-a-monotone-on-0-1#2700188) and its stochastic analogue. I'm wondering if there are some applications, if any, on stochastic control of dynamical systems (preferably with a concrete physical example).

Any suggestions would be appreciated!